# How is "æ" supposed to be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, ae-raising

The Encyclopædia Brittanica still uses the symbol "æ". However, I still hear everyone pronounce it as "Encyclo *pee* dia", when their spelling suggests more along the lines of "Encyclo *pah* dia" or "encyclo *pay* dia". In a more general sense, should æ or Æ always be pronounced as a long e sound? When I see it used, it is in dæmon, æther, or æon.

[The wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86) makes it clear that they should be pronounced with another sound along the lines of ah or eh... confusing because I want to pronounce it as "ai" or "ay". Given the name "Aion" as a recent videogame, and the common pronunciation of a CS mailer-daemon as "Daymon", clearly others behave the same way.

The problem lies in that  æ used to be pronounced as ah/eh, and now seems to be pronounced as ay. Encyclopædia is the only exception... being pronounced as ee?

How do I pronounce it when seen in English? ee, ay, or ah/eh?

Comment: There’s no simple answer to any question of the form “How is _<letter>/<digraph>_ pronounced?” It depends. As you’ll have seen in the Wikipedia article, what would have been pronounced /ai/ in Latin is usually pronounced /iː/ in English, but there are inevitably exceptions like the name _Æleen_, or examples like _paedophile_ where the British rendering /iː/ goes through both a spelling and a pronunciation change to become /ɛ/ in American English. And that’s to say nothing of the _Mediæval Bæbes_...

Comment: Encyclopaedia does not contain, and has never contained the letter 'Ash'. It is however sometimes written with the digraph 'æ', which has only an accidental resemblance to the ash.

Comment: Fairly recently, there was an amusing and very rare coincidence.
A local plumber has his name on his trucks as "Æ Carter". His first name is Archibald, though.
Considering that the letter/digraph is called "ash", it was amusing while Ash*. Carter was iirc Secretary of Defense. *Ashton, iirc

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to distinguish English vowels from English orthography. There are between twelve and fifteen [distinct vowels in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), depending on your dialect, but there are only 5 vowel letters in the orthography. This causes no end of problems.

The letter *æ* was used in Old English to represent the vowel that's pronounced in Modern English *ash, fan, happy,* and *last:* /æ/. Mostly we now spell that vowel with the letter **a**, because of the [Great Vowel Shift](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler//GreatVowelShift.pdf).

When *æ* appears in writing Modern English, it's meant to be a typographic variant of *ae*, and is pronounced the same as that sequence of vowel letters would be. So *Encyclopaedia* or *Encyclopædia*, no difference.

Comment: Even Encyclopaedia Brittanica pronounces it as a long e sound, in their ads and so on. According to your answer, that is wrong. Is such a major organization, who should clearly understand pronunciation, making an error in their own name?

Comment: Perhaps you should highlight more prominently: it's not the *ash*, it's the *ae*-ligature.

Comment: As I said, you have to distinguish English spelling from pronunciation. There's no difference between the letters"ae" together and the "æ" ligature; and there's no rule for how to pronounce them, either -- every word is different. The words _encyclopædia, encyclopedia,_ and _encyclopaedia_ are all pronounced the same, however you pronounce them. I pronounce that vowel as /i/, myself.

Comment: When æ appears in writing Modern English, [it] is pronounced the same as that sequence of vowel letters would be.              
Encyclopædia, encyclopedia, and encyclopaedia are all pronounced the same.           
I feel like those statements conflict. I wouldn't pronounce ae and e the same way. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: This answer is exactly right. BTW, I’ve been told that the Encyclopædia Britannica retains that particular spelling/glyphic expression because that is the form under which they first acquired the trademark, and so they have to keep using it that way. The OED2 used *æ* for things like *Cæsar*, but those are now invariably separated out as *ae* in the OED3 (OED Online), where the only instances of *æ* you ever find are original Old English (like OE *wræððu* > modern *wrath*) or the occasional Icelandic bit, as they still use “ash” (< *æsc*) there in Iceland.

Comment: @Lawton - You're missing the fact that English spelling [does not represent English pronunciation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54711/how-to-pronounce-the-letter-i/54717#54717) -- and was not meant to represent it, whatever they told you in school. It represents [Middle English pronunciation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67135/pronunciation-of-letter-y-asylum-vs-syrup/67139#67139), not Modern English. Don't look at spelling and expect to get pronunciation; it doesn't work that way. Sorry.

Comment: @Lawton: Consider *aestivation/estivation, aestrus/estrus, anaemia/anemia, archaeologist, bacteraemia/bacteremia, paean, paediatric/pediatric*, &c. Perhaps also consider *amoeba/ameba, apnoea/apnea, oestrogren/estrogen, diarrhoea/diarrhea, oecology/economy, logorrhoeic/logorrheic, coelacanth, oenology, Phoebe, phoenix, subpoena, ooecium/oecium*.  In all cases I can think of in classically derived words, whether it is spelled *æ/ae/e* or *œ/oe/e* makes no difference (French imports like *bœuf, hors d’œuvre, cri de cœur, trompe l’œil* don’t count—just Latin or Greek for *ae* and Greek for *oe*.)

Comment: @tchrist You convinced me. I wasn't buying the answer because I felt that the edge case still wasn't explained; why does Brittanica use the archaic ae but pronounce it as ee. The business logic that they must use the same name to keep the trademark explains the contradiction. Thanks.

Comment: @Lawton: trademark restrictions may be one explanation, but you may see 'ae' elsewhere where trademark isn't involved. There the explanation would be that it is an archaic spelling, like all of tchrist's alternate spellings.

Comment: @Mitch The British don’t always consider the *ae* or *oe* spellings archaic, although most are perceived as such in America. You’d have to ask someone from the UK or Ireland what their own take on those is. I just know that when doing NLP work (read: using a computer for natural language processing, as it is termed) on biomedical journal articles, you have to be especially careful for those variants, as they are not at all uncommon there (like in *The Lancet*). You sometimes even get the ligature versions.

Comment: @tchrist: Slight pedantic niggle—Icelandic does not now use, nor has it ever used, the letter _ash_. Rather, it uses the letter _æ_. The name _ash_ is only used for the letter as used in (various older stages of) English.

Comment: Although American spelling tends to be (slightly) more logical than British, there's a good reason for keeping 'ae' and 'oe', whether or not they're joined into æ and œ: in a word like mediaeval, if the 'ae' in simplified to 'e', it then gets treated as if it belongs with the preceding 'i'.  Hence the common US pronunciation /məˈdiːvl̩/ contrasted with British /ˌmɛdɪˈiːvl̩/.  OK, usage rules, but in this case the US version seriously obscures the etymology.

Comment: Virtually all pronunciation obscures the etymology, since the etymology is enshrined in the unphonetic spelling. I'm a linguist, and I **like** being able to see the fossils popping up in words; it helps my spelling, in fact, because I know many of the historical sound changes. Reading for me is like a visit to the Grand Canyon for a geologist. But not everybody is like me, and I don't flatter my idiolect or dialect as anything like "logical". They're all arbitrary, like wildflowers. That's the way living things stay living.

Comment: John, of course you're right.  I'm a complete amateur  -  no language skills beyond O-levels  -  but I found your diagram of I.E. *gen- utterly fascinating.

Comment: @John Lawler: How does this answer the original question? You give the pronunciation in Old English but not the usual pronunciation in modern English, which is what the original poster was asking for guidance on.

Comment: @sumelic: As noted in the comments above, the question was poorly phrased and presupposed that a vowel letter **has** a "usual pronunciation". This is not true. Since there is no answer to a question with a false presupposition (the prototypic example question is _Have you stopped beating your wife?_), this answer doesn't contain it. Plus, I feel no obligation to answer questions here exactly as they are posed, nor to preserve all the silly ideas that people have been taught in primary school or English class.

Comment: @ John Lawler: Do you really mean to suggest that English orthography has no relation to pronunciation? That's just not true; despite the oddities of English spelling, most of the time it is possible to predict the pronunciation of a word from the spelling. This is even more true of Latinate words, where the "ae" digraph is normally found.

Comment: Read the comments. English orthography is a pretty good fit for Middle English -- at least some dialects -- but most dialects of Modern English have upwards of a dozen vowel phonemes, which must be represented by five vowel letters, none of which have "standard pronunciations". They can't; they're like puzzle pieces identifying particular words for readers, but they no longer represent the pronunciation of Modern English.

Comment: This is not to say there is no relationship, merely that the relationship is **not** regular, but rather historical and therefore quite arbitrary, like all history. If you care to take the course (roughly, a full year college-level course in History of the English Language and PIE, with Intro Ling and Into Phonetics as prerequisites), then you too can see the glorious word fossils appearing in the spelling and not the pronunciation (like those silent GH's, which are vanished velar [x] allophones of Middle English /h/; or umlaut producing _goose_ and _geese, cow_ and _kine_).

Comment: @John Lawler: But the relationship is clearly not just diachronic. If I invent a word "greep", and you read it on the screen, you'll have a pretty good idea what the pronunciation is. This has nothing to do with the history of Middle English; it's about the  patterns of the current relationship between English spelling and pronunciation. The phonemic information in English spelling isn't just fossilized, it's part of the modern spelling system as well. That's why we spend time in school teaching the phonic system for reading, rather than teaching each word independently.

Comment: @Mitch Archaic? I think not. Examples besides encyclopaedia: oesophagus, gonorrhoea, anaesthesia, aesthetic etc. There are many more. (Funny you'd refer to anaesthesia in your answer - I didn't see it before my comment. Anyway I don't consider it archaic at all at least in so far as spelling goes.)

Comment: @Pryftan In American standard spelling, of those you just mentioned, only 'aesthetic' is the way it is written the others drop the non-e letter. You may see the others but those are much much rarer and are not considered standard. If you are used to British English spellings then the frequencies may be different (as noted by tchrist).

Answer (score 17):

English orthography is rule based...except it's not very good at following the rules. Sometimes it uses a regular literal one-to-one pronunciation, at oher times the spelling got stuck centuries ago but sounds changes occurred in speech, and sometimes, the word is written as from the foreign language it was borrowed from but the impossible or unlikely pronunciation is adapted to English mouths and ears.

The pair 'ae' or the single mushed together symbol 'æ', is not pronounced as two separate vowels. It comes (almost always) from a borrowing from Latin. In the original Latin it is pronounced as /ai/ (in IPA) or to rhyme with the word 'eye'. But, for whatever reason, **it is usually pronounced as '/iy/' or "ee"**. Encyclodpeeedia, alumneee (for many female 'alumnae'). Another variant is **/ɛ/ in an-eh-sthetic for 'anaesthetic'**. Note that many of these spellings are now variants and the more common spelling removes the strange looking 'a'.

Another pair borrowed from Latin is 'oe' is in (the old fashioned spelling) 'oesophagus' where it is pronounced /ɛ/ 'eh' eh-sah-fuh-gus.

Comment: Mitch, see [my comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70927/how-is-ae-supposed-to-be-pronounced/70938#comment137174_70938). BTW, when I was taught Latin, we were actually told to pronounce *ae* as `/ae/`, but everyone turned the `/e/` into the familiar glide of English *mice*.

Comment: @tchrist: thanks for that list of many examples. That's was what I was alluding to. I only answered separately from JL because i felt there needed to be a direct answer to the OP's 'How do you pronounce it?'

Comment: The original pronunciation of æ/ae in Latin was indeed /ai/, as in the Greek αι. However during the late republic and into the early empire, this shifted to /ae̯/, which eventually ended up as an /eː/.

Answer (score 8):

You may be mixing up the IPA pronunciation symbol *æ* and the alphabetic letter *æ*.

In English text, the letter is used as a slightly old-fashioned form of the Latin digraph *ae* (also in Latin-mediated Greek words) and in some names from Danish, Norwegian, Old English and a few other languages that use the letter natively.

The pronunciation doesn't have to be anything like the IPA [æ].

For Latin loanwords in ordinary English text, it's essentially equivalent to the letter "e" (so always "encyclopEEdia", "julius cEEsar") but in the study of Latin language and culture it's common to pronounce names and terms in ways more similar to how the original speakers did.

In Danish (etc.) names, you'd adapt to what ever approach you would otherwise use for those names in English text. It may end up actually sounding like the IPA [æ].

Answer (score 7):

To find out how a word is pronounced, you can look in a dictionary. To find out how a word "should" be pronounced, you have to decide what you mean by that, and then look up whatever information you think is relevant (e.g. the word's etymology, the frequency of any variant pronunciations, what usage "mavens" have written about the word).

The symbol *æ* has multiple distinct uses.

### A ligature of the Latin *ae* digraph

In fact, *æ* isn't used much at all in modern English writing, but most of the time when you see it in that context, it is not being used as a distinct letter, but just a ligature of the Latin-derived digraph *ae* (which is the letter *a* followed by the letter *e*). Writing this digraph with a ligature has fallen out of fashion, but some writers may use it to create a particular effect, or just out of eccentricity (compare perhaps the similarly uncommon use of the diaeresis in words like *coöperation*). Related questions: [Is the word “formulæ” valid English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41321), [Is it acceptable that I use ligatures and diæreses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326952) In many words, it is usual to write *e* instead of either *ae* or *æ*: this statement is true especially in American English, but there are many words for which it applies to British English as well. For example, the spelling *demon,* which is usual in both American English  and British English when writing about evil spirits or supernatural entities, comes from a spelling variant of Latin *daemon.* On the other hand, one word where *ae* is still common in both British English and American English is *aesthetic(s).*

As others have mentioned, the Latin *ae* digraph in English words is usually pronounced as /iː/ (the "long e" or "ee" sound found in the word *fleece*) : this definitely is true for *aeon, aether,* and *encylopaedia.*

Sometimes, especially in American English, Latin *ae* is instead pronounced as /ɛ/ (the "short e" sound found in the word *dress*). This pronunciation tends to occur in "closed" syllables (a closed syllable is a syllable that ends in a consonant) or in stressed syllables that are followed by at least two other syllables. An example is the word ***ae***sthete, which is pronounced with /ɛ/ in American English, although in British English it may be pronounced with /iː/. This same pronunciation difference (/ɛ/ in American English, /iː/ in British English) may occur for words that are spelled with "e" in American English but "ae" in British English (Brian Nixon mentioned the example *pedophile* vs. *paedophile* in a comment).

A third pronunciation, /eɪ/ ("long a", as in *face*), exists for *ae* in words taken from Latin, but it's a bit harder to explain, so I've postponed my discussion of it to the end of this answer. Also, I think it's not very common for words pronounced with /eɪ/ to be written with the ligature *æ.*

#### Latin *ae* was not always a digraph

In Latin, not all instances of the sequence *ae* were examples of the *ae* digraph. Occasionally, *a* followed by *e* in Latin just represented an "a" sound followed by an "e" sound, pronounced "in hiatus"; that is, in separate syllables (for example, in the Latin words *[aeneus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daeneus)* adj. "of bronze/of copper/brazen" and *[aer](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daer)* "air").

But related word in modern English may have developed pronunciations without hiatus, perhaps in part because of the ambiguous spellings or analogy with related words that are pronounced without a hiatus: e.g. *aeneous* (OED pronunciation: "Brit. /ˈiːnɪəs/, /eɪˈiːnɪəs/,  U.S. /ˈiniəs/, /eɪˈiniəs/") and *aerial* (OED pronunciation: "Brit. /ˈɛːrɪəl/,  U.S. /ˈɛriəl/").

In theory, words with *ae* in hiatus should not be written with the ligature *æ,* but in practice, it's possible to find examples of this from times when *æ* was more common.

### The Old English "ash" letter

In Old English, *ae* and *æ* were used to represent the monophthong /æ/ (which could be short or long). In this context, the symbol *æ* came to be considered a letter of its own, with the name "ash" (in Old English, "æsc").

Rarely, you will see this symbol in a modern English text when somebody is using an Old English name like "Æthelred".

The pronunciation is usually an approximation of what we think the Old English pronunciation was, so something like the "short a" sound in the modern English word *trap* (IPA /æ/, or in some systems /a/), or perhaps for some speakers the "short e" sound in the modern English word *dress* (IPA /ɛ/).

The pronunciation of Old English "ash" is irrelevant to the pronunciation of the ligature *æ* in English words taken from Latin.

### History of the Latin "ae" digraph

The Latin *ae* digraph replaced an *ai* digraph that was used in Old Latin. Scholars think that the sound was pronounced as a diphthong [ai] in the Old Latin stage. Its reflexes in the Romance languages point to a monophthong *ɛ in the common ancestor of these languages ("Proto-Romance").

Based on the evidence, the reconstructed development of the Latin sound is from a diphthong [ai] or [aj], to a diphthong with a more open final element [aɪ] or [ae], to a monophthong [ɛː], which merged with the reflex of the Latin "short e" sound to become *ɛ in Proto-Romance. (In some cases, Latin "ae" instead corresponds to Romance /e/: this is thought to represent an alternative development where at some earlier point before the loss of vowel length, *ae* became a long monophthong and merged with Latin "long e", which became Proto-Romance *e.)

During the Classical period, Latin *ae* was used as a transcription of the Greek digraph *αι.* The words *demon, aether/ether, aeon/eon* all come from Greek words spelled with *αι*: *δαίμων, αἰθήρ, αἰών.*

The conventional correspondence of Latin *ae* and Greek *αι* was maintained in "Classical" words in modern languages for a while, but eventually some scholars came to feel that the direct transliteration *ai* was somehow better or more appropriate. So in the modern English spelling of recent borrowings from or coinages based on Ancient Greek, we see variation between *ae* and *ai* (compare similar variation between *oe* and *oi*, *y* and *u, u* and *ou, c* and *k*). For example, the spelling *daimon* has been used by authors who wanted to use the Greek word *δαίμων* in English while avoiding the connotations of the word *demon.*

Part of the variability in the pronunciation of *ae* in modern English may also be based on the efforts of classical scholars. As I mentioned, Latin *ae* is reconstructed as having the pronunciation /aɪ/ at some point after the Old Latin period and before the end of the Classical Latin period. Latin teachers in favor of using a "restored" pronunciation decided that because of this, the English sound /aɪ/ (the "long i" sound found in the word *price*) should be taught to English-speaking Latin students as the pronunciation of Latin *ae.*

A number of speakers now use these "restored" qualities in certain contexts in English words that come from Latin. I mainly hear /aɪ/ for *ae* from modern English speakers when the *ae* is word-final—there is a separate question asking about the variation between /aɪ/ and /iː/ in this context: [Pronunciation of words ending with “‑ae”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40671/pronunciation-of-words-ending-with-ae).

### The "ay" pronunciation (IPA /eɪ/)

As mentioned in the question, there are a few words spelled with *ae* that seem to have pronounciations with the "long a" sound, as in the word *face* (IPA /eɪ/).

The origins of this are not entirely clear to me. It seems likely that in at least some cases, it is based on the medieval or "Ecclesiastical" pronunciation of Latin *ae* as a monophthong like [ɛ] or [e] (compare the use of English /eɪ/ in certain English pronunciations of a number of words that have /ɛ/ in modern French, such as *ballet* and *crêpe*).

It may also be influenced by the use of "a" + a consonant letter + "silent e" as a representation of /eɪ/ in native English words, and the use of "oe", "ie", "ue" as a representation of word-final "long o", "long i" and "long u" in a number of words.

In addition to *daemon,* the word *aegis* (mentioned in a comment by Lambie) has a variant pronunciation with /eɪ/ instead of /iː/. The sound /eɪ/ is also used as a third variant pronunciation of the *-ae* plural ending, in words like *vertebrae.*

Comment: Could you give the basic difference for aegis in BrE and AmE, for example?? Words that originally had ligatures in contrast to words like aesthetic where the ae is the same in both, if that was? Also, in encyclopedia, same sound in both, right? No one is saying these things.

Comment: @Lambie: Hmm, I'm not sure ... there are a lot of examples, so there may not be one single rule for the differences between BrE and AmE. I wrote an answer to a separate question about the pronunciation of "aegis": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438507/pronunciation-of-aegis

Comment: What I mean is that there are only so many classes or categories of the ex-ligature appearing in English. I would have grouped them and shown how some differ in AmE and BrE and some do not. See what I mean? My first comment provides an example of that.

Comment: You say *'In fact, æ isn't used much at all in modern English writing'* but it should be noted that although the character æ isn't used often the letters ae are.

Comment: Excellent answer. You mention that you are unsure where the "ay" pronunciation comes from. I would think it comes from English speakers who unconsciously know that a silent 'e' after a vowel makes the vowel long: "Rae", "Mae", "sundae", "toe", "pie", "cue", etc.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, "ae" or "oe" will result in a long or short "e" sound.
These spellings originated in Greek and found their way into English. Many
of them have changed as spelling is "reformed," but others have not.

Examples:

- Oedipus - "oed" = "ed"
- oesophagus - usually spelled "esophagus" now
- Aegypt - now spelled "Egypt"
- anaesthetic - sometimes spelled "anesthetic"
- paedophile - now spelled "pedophile"

As for "daemon" -- despite what you will hear from some computer people, it
is pronounced "demon" -- and despite what you will hear from some others, 
they are really only variant spellings. The older spelling "daemon" came to
be used in the computer sense, similar to when the "compact disc" was introduced to an international English-speaking audience, the original "disc" was used, even though the spelling of "disc" had mostly been reformed to "disk" by that time.  This resulted in the current situation in which "compact disc" and "hard disk" are spelled differently.

Now... When "ae" is used at the end of a Latin word, it is technically 
pronounced "eye." I say "technically" because it's confusing that the "real" 
pronunciation of "alumnae" sounds like the the popular pronunciation of 
"alumni" (which "really" should be pronounced "ah-loom-nee" which probably
only happens inside a Latin classroom.

Comment: I pronounce *alumni* to rhyme with *knee*, and *alumnae* to rhyme with *nigh*, as do most of the British people I know.

Comment: You say: *"...despite what you will hear from some computer people, it is pronounced 'demon' "*. This is an inherent contradiction. You are describing a pronunciation that is actively used, yet you appear to be prescribing an alternative pronunciation.

Comment: No no. Oesophagus is how you spell it. It's American that has it without the O. And Americans spell the anaesthetic/anaesthesia without the A before the E. Also Americans spell paedophile without the A (they also pronounce it differently). As for computer people I *do* pronounce *daemon* as *demon* (and yes I'm a Unix programmer so I know well what daemons are).

Comment: @JerryW. But it still should be noted that that is how your pronounce it whether or not the answer is contradicting itself.

Answer (score 2):

Encyclopaedia is a Greek work. It is a compound word and it has three morphemes: en - cyclo - paedia, meaning in - cycle - education (general education).Paedia comes from the Greek word παιδεία /pε:δΙ'Λ/. So, the spelling is influenced by the Greek spelling just like all the other Greek words mentioned above in other posts. In some cases pronunciation stays the same as in Greek like in anaesthetic.

Comment: Etymology from OED: **mid 16th century: modern Latin, from pseudo-Greek enkuklopaideia for enkuklios paideia ‘all-round education’.**

Comment: Here's the full note from the OED (2nd ed) **encyclopædia**, **encyclopedia**  (ɛnˌsaɪkləʊˈpiːdɪə) [a. late L. encyclopædia, a. pseudo-Gr. ἐγκυκλοπαιδεία, an erroneous form (said to be a false reading) occurring in MSS. of Quintilian, Pliny, and Galen, for ἐγκύκλιος παιδεία `encyclical education', the circle of arts and sciences considered by the Greeks as essential to a liberal education (cf. encyclical A. 1).  The spelling with æ has been preserved from becoming obs. by the fact that many of the works so called have Latin titles, as *Encyclopædia* *Britannica,* *Londinensis*, etc.]

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard an American say it any other way than  "Encyclo-pee-dia". I have no research to back up that pronunciation, but you will not sound strange if you say it that way. (among Americans)

Comment: It's the same in Britain; the difference is that *anaemia*, for example, is here pronounced with the long e but spelt ae. OPs question seems to spring from a transatlantic misunderstanding.

Comment: @TimLymington More like a difference of spelling. But maybe that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

The Danish alphabet has both the mentioned vocals, ae = æ and oe = ø. Æ is pronounced very close to e in *echo*, and when I read the English word *encyclopædia* I naturally pronounce it as described, confusing an American listener. ø or oe is pronounced as the German ö, also as a single sound. Needless to say, I'm Danish.

Comment: The question specifically asked about rules for "ae" in general, not about the pronunciation of the specific word "encyclopaedia" or about the pronunciation in other languages.

Comment: @herisson Also it's incorrect even for British English; it's a long E. To martin: you might point out that German ö can be spelt oe (so can ä be ae and ü be ue) if you don't have the umlaut (or more like you're lazy).