# Pronunciation of Aegis

Tags: pronunciation

I say āgis Google says ēgis.
Is it regional or am I just pronouncing it wrong?
I live in the midwest near Chicago with that helps.

Comment: For what it's worth, my Webster's dictionary gives both pronunciations.

Comment: I still think of it as the Greek word for *breastplate*, having learnt Ancient Greek at school; so in my head I say 'aɪɡɪs, but out loud I say ˈiːdʒɪs so that people don't think I'm weird.

Comment: If you ever have a pronunciation question, it is always best to check an accredited dictionary, namely Merriam-Webster and the OED.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any clear definition of what "pronouncing it wrong" means that would be applicable in this case, so this part of the question cannot really be answered.

The pronunciation with the "long e" sound (the vowel in the word *fleece*) is more in line with the tradition of pronouncing the digraph *ae* the same as the letter *e* in English words from Latin and Greek. The pronunciation with the "long e" sound is also more clearly established in the sense that there are a number of dictionaries that give it as the only pronunciation, such as the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=aegis) and the [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aegis).

But the pronunciation of *aegis* with the "long a" sound has evidently become somewhat common for some reason. As Bread mentions in a comment, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aegis) lists this as a possible pronunciation.

In terms of regional patterns, the Oxford English Dictionary implies that the pronunciation with the "long a" sound is more common in American English than in British English by giving the pronunciation as follows:

> Brit. /ˈiːdʒɪs/,  U.S. /ˈidʒᵻs/, /ˈeɪdʒᵻs/

However, I don't know of any patterns for the distribution of the pronunciations of *aegis* that have been identified beyond that. Since it is a fairly uncommon word, I would imagine that many people base their pronunciation on the spelling, so I wouldn't expect to see very strong regional trends.

Comment: I wonder if the U.S. pronunciation of *Aegis* is influenced by the various related [naval weapons systems](http://www.navy.mil/navydata/fact_display.asp?cid=2100&tid=200&ct=2) of the same name. The military is a case where the correct pronunciation would be however which way the admiral pronounces it. The ACS system had a good amount of news coverage because it was implicated (but exonerated) in the Iran Air Flight 655 catastrophe, and ABMD a little bit these days because of the ballistic missile threat from North Korea.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster (and also the OED I believe) has two pronunciations for “aegis”: ējis (where the *e* vowel sounds the same as in “eat”) and ājis (where the *a* vowel sounds the same as in “ate”.) Neither is wrong and both are correct.

Comment: OED (at least my 2nd Edition version) only has the long E pronunciation:  **ægis**  /ˈiːdʓɪs/ [L. ægis, a. Gr. αἰγίς]
http://ipa-reader.xyz/?text=%CB%88i%CB%90d%CA%92%C9%AAs