# When is the "Short A" sound actually spelled with an AE?

Tags: orthography, vowels, phonemes

I was reading a book on English spelling (***Dictionary of the British English Spelling System***, by Greg Brooks) and it mentioned that the Short A sound (æ) can be spelled using the following graphemes:

- **a**, as in cat
- **i**, as in timbre
- **ai**, as in plaid
- **al**, as in salmon
- **ei**, as in reveille (only in British English)

It also mentions in a table that the Short A sound can be spelled with the letters **ae**.  But I didn't see any examples in the book.

Does anyone know of any words that have the letters "ae" used to make the Short A sound (æ)?  A single example would be really helpful - and an exhaustive list would be even better.

Comment: I often hear "anaesthetic" pronounced with a short A in the second syllable. It is not accented though, so is not clear.

Comment: I think of it as a silent "l" in "salmon", rather than "al" making the short "a" sound.  Apparently, the "l" in "salmon" has never been pronounced but was introduced to bring the word closer to its Latin original.  In French (where we got it from) it is still "saumon".

Comment: Well, the A in your example "cat" is a short A, so it's either referring back to that example or maybe incorrectly referring to an A that makes a schwa (ə) sound. In the English name "Michael," "ae" has that sound. Your question is difficult to impossible to answer since either you or that book is incorrect in premise, making any answer, at best, a stab in the dark.

Comment: Hello Benjamin, the grapheme A does make the /æ/ phoneme 50% of the time.  The "A, as in cat" example was meant to refer to that.  Sorry for the confusion if I worded it incorrectly!  Let me know a better way to word it and I'm happy to edit.

Comment: The short æ sound was actually spelled "æ" (which was a single letter called "Ash", not the pair of letters "ae") in Old English. Ælfrik and Cædmon mentioned in the answer were of course Old English words which later fell out of use, and whose spelling was never "modernized."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman the modern pronunciation of "Michael" is a typical example of English retainig the spelling of a foreign word but mangling the original pronunciation - compare "Michael" and "Israel" which are both Hebrew. In musical settings  at least, Israel usually retains its correct 3 syllables, "Is-ra-el".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not common for the digraph ⟨ae⟩ to represent /æ/. ⟨ae⟩ is [usually pronounced](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/457060/365490):

- **/iː/** (*encyclopaedia, aether, aeon*)
- **/ɛ/** (*aesthetics, aerial* in AmE)
- **/eə/** or **/ɛː/** (*aeroplane, aerial* in BrE).

The only word where ⟨ae⟩ represents /æ/ I've been able to find is *Gaelic*: /ˈɡ**æ**l.ɪk/. However, it's also pronounced with the diphthong /eɪ/: /ˈɡ**eɪ**.lɪk/.

As @LPH pointed out in a comment, *Caedmon* and *Aelfrik* are two other words that have ⟨ae⟩ represent /æ/.

Comment: You can add "Aelfrik" (abbot)  and "Caedmon" (English poet, flourished 658–680). (only  æ for both)

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks to you both!